# integrate spring security 3.1 with existing app

Tags: java, spring, security, jdbc

I want to integrate spring security in my application.
The users'information is saved in an Oracle DB where the passwords are encoded with md5.
I tried this at first but it didn't work :

```
 <bean id="customjdbcUserService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="enableAuthorities" value="true" />
            <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT mail,password,enabled FROM users WHERE mail = ?" />
            <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="select mail,authority from user_roles where mail = ?" />
            </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:8080/ex" />
            <property name="username" value="user1" />
            <property name="password" value="user1" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customjdbcUserService"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="authenticationManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
            <property name="providers">
                <list>
                    <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    <sec:authentication-manager>
 <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customjdbcUserService" >
      <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
     </security:authentication-provider> 
        </sec:authentication-manager>
```

I searched in the net and found a lot about implementing `UserDetailsService` or `authenticatioProvider` or `authenticationManager` or `Filter`. Now I am just confused : which one should I implement?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?. Do you get an error message? Besides that: you should not encode passwords with md5.

Comment: @micha when I press the connect button in my form, It doesn't go to the 'default-target-url' page,but it reset my login form..and about the passwords, they are already encoded in the DB that I have, it was not my choice

Answer (score 1):

implementing UserDetailsService would be great for authenticating user,

**Spring Security xml code**

```
  <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailService">

    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

**service class that implements, org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService**

```
  @Service("userDetailsService")
  public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
  {

  }
  //methods an your code/logics

  }
```